# Найти последний элемент в списке

Tags: scala

Как найти последний элемент списка без использования функции last?Вроде есть два способа-циклический и рекурсивный.
Пример:
scala> last(List(1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8))

res0: Int = 8

Я могу для этого примера написать
println(x.tail.tail.tail.tail.tail.head)
Но это только для этого списка.А мне нужно для любого,в общем случае сделать.
Пробовал еще циклом
for(i<-x) x=x.tail
В это случае список станет пустым,х-1 тут не напишешь.Тогда я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: Через case matching    
case head :: Nil => print head    
case _ => // recurse

Answer (score 0):

Если не устраивает именно метод, можно написать то же самое по другому `list.takeRight(1)` или `list.apply(list.size)` и обработать вариант пустого списка. Если через рекурсию, то

```scala
@tailrec
def last[A](list: List[A]): A = {
  list match {
    case head :: Nil => head
    case head :: tail => last(tail)
  }
}
```

и тоже обработать вариант пустого списка согласно требованиям.